# find duplicate value in multidimensional array and combine their ID in comma separated with accordingly using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, unique

I have multidimensional array which listed in dynamically call from the database where need to have apply filter on conditional base of unique `value` and their `ID` merge with comma separated accordingly as with below desired result.

```
$arr = array();

$arr[0]['attribute'] = 'A';
$arr[0]['value'] = array('tenghao','Yuncheng','TAIFENG','Xinsheng','Laiwu Wanxin');
$arr[0]['ID'] = array(3561,3568,3560,3567,3569);

$arr[1]['attribute'] = 'B';
$arr[1]['value'] = array('Red, Red','Red','Red','Red','Red', 'Red');    
$arr[1]['ID'] = array(3567,3569,3561,3568,3569,3560);

$arr[2]['attribute'] = 'C';
$arr[2]['value'] = array("90%","80%","80%-100%","90%","100%");    
$arr[2]['ID'] = array(3567,3569,3561,3568,3560);
```

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => A
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tenghao
                    [1] => Yuncheng
                    [2] => TAIFENG
                    [3] => Xinsheng
                    [4] => Laiwu Wanxin
                )

            [ID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3561
                    [1] => 3568
                    [2] => 3560
                    [3] => 3567
                    [4] => 3569
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => B
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Red, Red
                    [1] => Red
                )

            [ID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3567
                    [1] => 3569,3561,3568,3569,3560
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [attribute] => C
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 90%
                    [1] => 80%
                    [2] => 80%-100%
                    [3] => 100%
                )

            [ID] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3567,3568
                    [1] => 3569
                    [2] => 3561
                    [3] => 3560
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I would not call what your phpfiddle contains an actual attempt to solve the problem - you are not actually doing anything in there, that works towards solving this problem. Sorry, but this looks like an “alibi attempt” to me - _pretending_ that you actually tried. (And for a “Senior Software Engineer”, that is a bit too little, if you asked me.)

Comment: its an open forum and it doesn't matter about my designation if we are stuck somewhere then we have right to ask question using this medium. if we have no idea how to get it resolve then to away from there.@04FS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next code for getting your result:

```
$ar_res  = []; 

foreach($arr as $ind => $row){  

    $vals = [];    // array with unique values
    $ids = [];     // array with joined ids

    $ar_res[$ind]['attribute'] = $row['attribute'];     // copy attribute field

    foreach($row['value'] as $key => $val){

        // analysing each value of each row  

        if (in_array($val,$vals)){   
        // if it's an old value
        // then join corresponded ID

            $ids[array_search($val, $vals)] .= ', '.$row['ID'][$key];
        } else { 
            // if this is a new value 
            // then add corresponded ID with value in both arrays 

            $vals[] = $val;
            $ids[] = $row['ID'][$key];  
        } 
    }
    // resultant array
    $ar_res[$ind]['value'] = $vals;
    $ar_res[$ind]['ID'] = $ids;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PRo9t)